# There is no response when starting React, including "npm start" and "npm run start"

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I downloaded (git clone) 2 git repo, one of which is a React project. If I start it with the command `npm start` or `npm run start`, the terminal will stop at the last line and nothing happens:

```
> meetjobs@0.1.0 start
> PORT=3000 node server.js

Warning: React.createFactory() is deprecated and will be removed in a future major release. Consider using JSX or use React.createElement() directly instead.
listening on 3000...
```

I used the `npm run start-reactapp` command to successfully start the React website of the same PC (Win10), but now it only automatically opens the browser window, and shows the "localhost refused to connect" error.

Please tell me what I have overlooked.

Comment: see the scripts that are specified in the package.json instead of guessing

Comment: This has nothing to do with Git. You used Git to download the repository, but you also used your disk drive to store it; both play the same role at this point (i.e., none to speak of).

Comment: localhost 3000 can be started again, maybe it will take longer, I don’t know why